# Django Rest Framework Post method not allowed for a Route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm writing a rest API using Django rest framework, I have setup viewsets, serializers and routes in their corresponding files.But when I send a post request to a route it returns POST method not allowed.

Here's what i have done:

**viewsets.py**

```
class DocRestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DocRestSerializer
```

**routes.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'deployments', viewsets.DeploymentViewSet, base_name='rest_deployments')
router.register(r'rest_deployments', viewsets.DocRestViewSet, base_name='docrest_deployments')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DocRestSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = models.DocRestModel
    fields = ('name', 'user', 'serviceName', 'dockerImageURL', 'routing')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/new$', views.DeploymentView.as_view(), name='new-rest-dep'),
    url(r'^rest/$', views.DeploymentView.as_view(), name='doc-rest-dep'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class DocRestView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return 'Post req received for docrest'
```

> Update: Here's I have added users **urls.py** also:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dashboard/', include('gui.urls')),
    url(r'^instance/', include('instances.urls')),
    url(r'^images/', include(image_urls)),
    url(r'^restDeployment/', include('rest.urls')),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', views.Dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    url(r'^login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^deploy/docker/', include(auth_urls), name='authGoogle'),
    url(r'^deploy/', include(auth_urls), name='awd'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

]
```

and here's the **restDeployment** URL refers to the rest app urls.

When I submit a POST request to **`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/rest_deployments/`** it returns:

> {"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}

what can be a problem?

Comment: Did you add router.url to urls: `url(r'^users/', include(router.urls)),`?

Comment: yup, this app name is `rest` So, i have added `url(r'^restDeployment/', include('rest.urls')),` to the user's `urls.py`

Comment: Why do you have `DocRestViewSet` and `DocRestView` ? You just need the viewset

Comment: the `DocRestView` is pointed by an URL from `urls.py`.

Comment: Possibly having no `queryset` defined on ViewSet: see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset